# Office 2007 Excel opening error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2007

One of our employees is currently having an issue with Excel in Office 2007. When she tries to open an Excel document it displays the following error message: An error has occurred in sending the command to the application.

I have tried several solutions to this however none of them have worked.

- Uninstalling and reinstalling
- Set Excel to ignore DDEs
- Reset file associations
- Repairing Office
- Turned off Add-ins
- Installed Windows updates

I can't seem to find a working solution for this. The machine is running windows 7 and office 2007

Comment: You can try 2 more things: 1) disable hardware acceleration in excel. 2) Check compatibility settings in excel.exe properties (uncheck all or run as administrator)

Comment: Can you open that same file on another computer, that has the same version of Excel?

Comment: Is the file in a very long file path - i.e. lots of folders deep with long names?  And does the file open if she opens Excel first and then drags the file into the window?

Comment: BruceWayne - It's not just a single file, it's any file. And they all work on any other PC in the office.

Sir Adelaide - No folders in the way, just in my documents. If she opens excel first and then goes file > open she can open documents.